# Does a Samba workgroup with spaces need quotes around it?

Tags: samba, share, smb, workgroup

If my Windows workgroup is made of two words with a space in-between, does Samba's config file need quotes around the workgroup name, example: WORKGROUP = "MY WORKGROUP"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not. See `man smb.conf` - one of the first sections, `FILE FORMAT`, tells you:

```
   The values following the equals sign in parameters are all either a
   string (no quotes needed) or a boolean, which may be given as yes/no,
   1/0 or true/false.
```

So there you go - no you don't have to quote in smb.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces aren't allowed in NetBIOS names (such as a workgroup) so you're likely to run into problems later if you try to do this.